# Turn caps lock on automatically after a specific character?

Tags: android

I want the keyboard to automatically go to "capitalize mode" after typing a specific character. I.e. I want the keyboard to hit the "shift" button and capitalize the next letter after typing an open bracket ' (' or close bracket ')'.

I want this to act on the keyboard and be an option for the user so that they don't have to capitalize the next letter. I don't want to automatically capitalize the text before it appears in the editText because I want the user to have the option to not capitalize the next letter.

Comment: Unless you're writing the keyboard app, I'm fairly certain you can't. You can however attach a `TextWatcher` to your edit text and modify inputted characters manually.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done programmatically in your code base.

1. Set a **setKeyListener**.
2. insert an **if condition** where you check whether or not the entered character is equal to your **specific character**.
3. Capitalize your character using **TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS**.

I attached some docs below that you might found useful.

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.AllCaps.html

Comment: I believe this capitalises all characters. I'm looking to have the keyboard press the "shift" button after I press the open bracket. So by default the next letter will be a capital, but if the user hits the shift button again, the next letter won't be a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work :

```
public class CapitalizedEditText extends EditText {
    List<Integer> mKeyCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public CapitalizedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void capitalizeAfter(int... keyCodes) {
        for(int keyCode : keyCodes) {
            mKeyCodes.add(keyCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        setFilters(getInputFilter(keyCode));
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private InputFilter[] getInputFilter(int keyCode) {
        return mKeyCodes.contains(keyCode)
                ? new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()}
                : new InputFilter[] {};
    }
}
```

example :

```
((CapitalizedEditText) findViewById(R.id.editid))
                        .capitalizeAfter(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_A,
                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET,
                                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET);
```

will capitalize after specified keys